# Is COLLATION required in SELECT DISTINCT query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know how to enforce collation on a Select Distinct statement or whether it is even necessary.

```
-- Load temp Table
INSERT INTO tblTEST(srtTxt)
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[tblbackup].[srtTxt] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS FROM 
[D:\APP_DATA\TESTDB.MDF].[dbo].[tblbackup]
```

If I am trying to load distinct strings into a new table, is COLLATION enforced by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I cannot set collation on the destination column but only on the select column. I get errors no matter what I try

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to set the collation on the destination column.  But watch for collation-conversion errors.

Comment: So what would be the syntax?

Comment: --to view the collation
EXEC sp_help mytable

--to change it
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyCol VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL;

Comment: It appears I cannot set collation on the destination column but only on the select column. I get errors no matter what I try.